# Is it okay that in Laravel route file contains so many lines of routes?

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel routing file (routes/web.php) there are so many lines of routes. I think there's way to make it more collected. For example, Auth::routes() it's line of code but it contains about 3-4 routes. So how can I create smth like this in my web.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create in your controller a static function do define the routes you want to associate with the controller.

```
static function routes() {
  Route::group(array('prefix' => 'product'), function() {
    Route::get('/{id?}', array('as' => 'product.index', 'uses' => 'ProductController@index'));
  });
}
```

And than call it like this:

```
\App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::routes();
```

[Take a look on this question / Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-routing-as-authroutes)

Answer (score 1):

You can register additional routes files in the `App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file. By default it contains the API routes and web routes. All you'd have to do is create a function `mapXyzRoutes()` (for example) and mimic the code in the `mapWebRoutes()` function. Then, add the function call to the `map()` function of the RouteServiceProvider file.

You can add middleware, prefixes and namespaces here, which really helps keep a clean routes file.

Of course, you'll need to create the new file in the `/routes` directory, too.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's not easy to give you a response but you can check this :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers

for example writing this `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');`
will give you 6 routes to use your model.

it's useful if you're using classic "CRUD" routes on your models.

Answer (score -1):

**Implicit Controllers**

Laravel allows you to easily define a single route to handle every action in a controller. First, define the route using the Route::controller method:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

The controller method accepts two arguments. The first is the base URI the controller handles, while the second is the class name of the controller. Next, just add methods to your controller, prefixed with the HTTP verb they respond to:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

public function getIndex()
{
    //
}

public function postProfile()
{
    //
}

public function anyLogin()
{
    //
}

}
```

The index methods will respond to the root URI handled by the controller, which, in this case, is users.

If your controller action contains multiple words, you may access the action using "dash" syntax in the URI. For example, the following controller action on our UserController would respond to the users/admin-profile URI:

```
public function getAdminProfile() {}
```

For more refer this -[Implicit Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers)

Comment: I can't find this documentation entry if I switch to a newer version of laravel

Comment: yep, its deprecated from 5.3 onwards